# ajax in usercontrol

Tags: asp.net, ajax, user-controls, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Is it possible to use ajax controls (as it is) inside a user control?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by "as it is", but the answer is yes, you can use AJAX in user controls.

The normal practices regarding user controls still apply - using the `ScriptManager` in order to control javascript instances on the page, proper usage of ViewState etc.

Your question is rather vague, hence the fairly vague answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could use controls from the [Ajax Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/) in user controls. Just make sure that the page that hosts the user control has a ScriptManager or preferably a ToolScriptManager.

Answer (score 0):

Now things will change and need special attention when you use Dynamically loaded User Controls ( On Demand ) and Ajaxify them. Ajaxifying Dynamically loaded User controls at run-time though is simple and straightforward could be challenging... Hope this answers ur Q